# How to load extension to CefSharp Browser?

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have problem with load my extension to CefSharp.

Extension seems loaded, i catched breakpoint in OnExtensionLoaded() method, but nothing shows on screen, no alert and no console log, that i did in extension.

In Google Chrome extension work correctly, alert and console.log working good.

**C#**

> **CEF Initializing**

```
var settings = new CefSettings
{
    RootCachePath = PathSettings.RootCachePath,
    PersistSessionCookies = true,
    PersistUserPreferences = true,
    BackgroundColor = 255,
    CachePath = PathSettings.RootCachePath,
    CommandLineArgsDisabled = false,
    IgnoreCertificateErrors = true,
    RemoteDebuggingPort = 8080,
};

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-extension-activity-logging");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("extensions-on-chrome-urls");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("extensions-not-webstore");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("show-component-extension-options");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-running-insecure-content");

Cef.Initialize(settings, true);
```

> **ExtensionHandler.cs**

```
public class ExtensionHandler : IExtensionHandler
{
    public bool CanAccessBrowser(IExtension extension, IBrowser browser, bool includeIncognito, IBrowser targetBrowser)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public IBrowser GetActiveBrowser(IExtension extension, IBrowser browser, bool includeIncognito)
    {
        return browser;
    }

    public bool GetExtensionResource(IExtension extension, IBrowser browser, string file, IGetExtensionResourceCallback callback)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnBeforeBackgroundBrowser(IExtension extension, string url, IBrowserSettings settings)
    {
        
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnBeforeBrowser(IExtension extension, IBrowser browser, IBrowser activeBrowser, int index, string url, bool active, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings settings)
    {
        browser.ShowDevTools();
        return true;
    }

    public void OnExtensionLoaded(IExtension extension)
    {
    }

    public void OnExtensionLoadFailed(CefErrorCode errorCode)
    {
    }

    public void OnExtensionUnloaded(IExtension extension)
    {
    }
}
```

> **Browser initializing**

```
Browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(new RequestContextSettings
    {
        CachePath = cachePath,
        PersistSessionCookies = true,
        PersistUserPreferences = true,
        IgnoreCertificateErrors = true,
        AcceptLanguageList = "en"
    });

Browser.RequestContext.LoadExtensionFromDirectory(path, new ExtensionHandler());
```

**EXTENSION**

> **background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'console.log("console.log from extension");'
      });
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'alert("alert from extension");'
      });
    });
```

> **manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "BrowserExtension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Description ...",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Extension support is very limited, it's likely your extension uses APIs that haven't been implemented in CEF. Tabs is not supported from memory. Please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2497#issue-354965106 in detail.

Comment: CEF has recently introduced a new Chrome runtime and CefSharp start working on adopting it. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4123

We at DotNetBrowser has released a preview build with extensions support recently. Check it out: https://dev.to/dotnetbrowser/chrome-extensions-in-net-web-view-controls-11lm